# Which band beers exist in your country?

Tags: specialty-beers

Does your country have any band or music based special crafted beers?
In Finland I can get Mötorhead, Kiss, Iron Maiden and Finnish bands like Amorphis and soon Diablo's Corium Black titled beer.

I was wondering that if I could get information that different countries have band or music related beers I could order some online for educational purposes.

Comment: Here in Belgium I don't think we have any non-obscure beers particularly tied to a music group, of course there is a lot of music that goes with beer. I would therefore advise you to buy a students codex which is a book filled with songs to sing while getting drunk with lots of friends. This merry activity is called a 'Cantus' (or commercium or even commers) and is really something you should have done in your lifetime.  (comment because not really adding information)

Comment: Lost Abbey's [Track 8](http://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/18149/84414/) is a reference to Iron Maiden's Number of the Beast.

Comment: Hi Pole, this question doesn't look like a good fit for the Stack Exchange community as it is too broad. Questions should have a single, specific, and unambiguous answer.

Comment: [Related article in Italian](https://www.giornaledellabirra.it/mercato/la-mia-birra-suona-il-rock-la-nuova-frontiera-del-merchandising/) (but images and names of beers and bands such as Queen or Opeth can't be misunderstood)!

Answer (score 5):

In Brazil, we have a few. But, in general, they're not an original beer, really created by some musician, but more a marketing thing. They only contract a micro brewery to develop a recipe for then, or even use a previously existent beer and re-brand it with their names.

Examples are: Raimundos, Sepultura (which is a brazilian hardcore band well-known around the world) and Paralamas do Sucesso, bands which have a beer with their names produced by Bamberg Brewery, a microbrewery of São Paulo state dedicated exclusively to german styles. The former 2 being merely a re-brand of Bamberg's flagship beers.

Velhas Virgens is a rock band from São Paulo which have their own brand too, and more than one beer, and I think someone inside the band homebrew. Nowadays they produce in association with Invicta brewery, and I guess they have some contribution for them in the products development, although, of all those "rock band beers", they seem to be the most genuine/authentic initiative.

The way I see this thing on the craft beer scene is: people trying to take advantage of this trending market and make money out of it. It's a pure marketing thing. It's like you being a famous person and associating your name with some product, whatever it is, just because you know people will buy it only because of your image/name, and not because of what is really inside of it.

Particularly, I think this is pure opportunism.

Comment: Thank you I am specially interested on the Sepultura beer. Might be hard to order to Scandinavia tough.

Comment: Oh, for sure, hehe. But don't be too excited about it, it's just a regular hefeweizen.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a look at a large variety of the band beers available this is a great site where you can buy them: [Icon Beverages](http://www.iconbeverages.co.uk/).

Comment: Nice site. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 3):

In Russia we have ARIA (АРИЯ) heavy metal band branded beer, made by Faxe. Marketing way of Faxe. As presentation of this event the band played a concert right at the Faxe brewery.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In South Africa (where I am from) the band FokofPolisiekar had two beers.

In other countries: Queen has a Bohemian Pilsner.

Loosely related: Playboy also has their own beer. Not a band, I know.

Answer (score 2):

In Denver CO, Trve Brewing collaborates with a variety of metal bands for some if their beers.  There's also Black Sky and Black Shirt Brewing.

Then there's the E40 malt liquor, but I forget who brews it.

Answer (score 2):

In Texas, Real Ale brewed Iron Swan Ale for The Sword. They followed that up with another Sword branded beer, Ghost Eye.

Answer (score 1):

Hell, [yes](http://acdc-beverage.com/en/)!

[image: AC DC beer]
<sub>(source: [acdc-beverage.com](http://acdc-beverage.com/en/public/img/acdcthumb.jpg))</sub>

I have never drunk it though :)

**Update.**

- German rock band "[Die toten Hosen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Toten_Hosen)" ("The dead pants", means "deadly boring") has recently presented its own beer brewed in collaboration with a local brewery - "Hosen Hell" (don't be confused with "hell", it's German for "pale lager beer", so the skull is from the band's logo not from hell. See also note below)

[image]

- In Russia, there is "Leningrad band" beer named after Russian "[Leningrad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leningrad_(band))" band.

[image]

---

*Note: Same applies to "[Fucking Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fucking_Hell)". Fucking is a village in Austria, Hell is pale beer. But the name is obviously an intended pun.*

Comment: I had the one on the left. It is a normal German Pils. Nice, but nothing special.